# Need to Remove the Text before String using Notepoad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Requirement... I just need to Remove the Text before `<?xml` while preserving the content between every `<?xml` tag.

**Examples**

```
DEBUG 12 Jul 09:39:23 [PSE-10000000516] OnlinePublisher.java :120  -
Publishing

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        ABCD
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>
```

**and**

```
DEBUG 12 Jul 09:40:23 [JOB-660] OnlinePublisher.java :120  -
Publishing

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: "I need to remove the Text before The Text.", this isn't very clear, do you have an example input / desired output?

Comment: This isn't clear what you want to do... perhaps you should format the example (indent each line by at least 4 spaces so that they display as sample text)

Comment: Can you give a before and after example of what the string should be?

Comment: I have formatted the text..

Answer (score 1):

This is doing what you want:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^<>]+?(?=\R\s*<\?xml )`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^<>]+?     : 1 or more characters that is not < or >, not greedy
(?=         : start lookahead
  \R        : any kind of line break
  \s*       : 0 or more spaces
  <\?xml    : literally
)           : end lookahead
```

CHECK `. matches newline`

**Result for given example (4 times):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XMLDATA>
    <CHILD_DATA>
    ABCD
    </CHILD_DATA>
    </XMLDATA>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XMLDATA>
    <CHILD_DATA>
    ABCD
    </CHILD_DATA>
    </XMLDATA>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XMLDATA>
    <CHILD_DATA>
    ABCD
    </CHILD_DATA>
    </XMLDATA>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XMLDATA>
    <CHILD_DATA>
    ABCD
    </CHILD_DATA>
    </XMLDATA>
```

Comment: Hi Toto, This works if I have one XML in the file... But If I have many XML, it retains the 1st XML and remove all below XML..
For e.g.

Hello1  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        ABCD
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>

Hello2 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        XYZ
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>
With your above command, I will only have the XML with ABCD.

Comment: Hi Toto, I am sorry, the command is not able to find the String Literal..

Comment: @MithilShukla: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean by "String literal" ? Edit your question with sample blocks and expected result.

Comment: To Toto,
Following is the sample BLOCK
DEBUG 12 Jul 09:39:23 [PSE-10000000516] 120  - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        ABCD
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>
DEBUG 12 Jul 09:40:23 [JOB-660] :120  - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        XYZD
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>
DEBUG 12 Jul 09:51:16 [JOB-668] :120  - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        ZXSDFFF
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>

Comment: Expected Result:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        ABCD
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        XYZD
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <XMLDATA>
        <CHILD_DATA>
        ZXSDFFF
        </CHILD_DATA>
        </XMLDATA>

Comment: @MithilShukla: This is exactly what my regex does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `^(\w+.*\s+)(\w+\s)\s+`

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Replace
3. Select `regular expression`
4. Input the above regex in `Find what`
5. press `Replace`